# Piping construction, flanged connection - Difference between Collar and Flat collar

Tags: mechanical-engineering, piping

Consider a [collar](http://www.erv-gmbh.at/en/flanges-collars-butt-ends/167-v-boerdel-din-2642) (V-Bördel) and a [flat collar](http://www.erv-gmbh.at/en/flanges-collars-butt-ends/178-glatte-bunde-en-1092-1-typ-32) (glatter Bund) for a flanged connection, in conjunction with a loose flange.

What are reasons to use one over the other? I want to know because a tender specified a flat collar but it seems (I'm not on site, just helping with clerical work an spotting the discrepancy) the constructor installed collars. Most likely they simply got a better deal on the one type. Is there an important functional difference?

Comment: By `tender`, do you mean "vendor?"

Comment: other way round: the bid document specified flat collar, the contractor sold collar. Note that this question is purely about the technical differences, the contractual stuff I'll sort out IRL.

Comment: Ok, just trying to figure out who specified what here and why (might be needed for the answer, who knows?).